# returns id=1 after insert mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

Today I changed mysql to PDO. And now I have this little problem. 
So when I used mysql, and wanted to know the id of the row I just inserted I just had to do this:

```
$id = $obj_db_write->insert("reservations",$arr_kolommen,$arr_waardes);
```

When I printed the $id I got: (for example:) 5462

When I use the same line now, I get 1 as Id.

Problem: 
When the line is inserted, other columns are using that ID for adding fields in other tables. 
So now I get this error:

> **Warning**: `PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[23000]:`
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry `'1-double'` for key `'RSVR_ID'`
>   in `/data/local/www/wereldreizen/html/phpclasses/class_db.php` on line **229**

What's quite expected because the RSVR_ID is 1, and 1 is already inserted.

Does someone know where I'm wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PDO, you don't get the newly inserted ID as result from a query. Use

```
PDO::lastInsertId
```

instead. In your case, that could e.g. look like that:

```
 $affectedRows = $obj_db_write->exec(your-insert-statement);
 $lastInsertedID = $obj_db_write->lastInsertId();
```

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php for the full PDO API.

Comment: I found my previous mistake: I wrote lastinsertedId insead of lastInsertedId. But now I have another warning:Warning: PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Comment: Ok found my problem. I had to write the query if($this->db->query($insert)){
             $waarde = $this->db->lastInsertId();
                  return $waarde; in the if instead of before. ) thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3):

The last auto insert id is available via [PDO::lastInsertId](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) and the method you're calling should return that value; something like

```
class ... {
   public function insert(...) {
      ...
      return $this->pdo->lastinsertid();
   }
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answer, but I still have a little problem. I have now this: $waarde = $this->db->lastinsertid; but I now get this warning: Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$lastinsertid. With mysql was it easy I just had to use: $waarde = mysql_insert_id($this->db);

Comment: sorry, forgot the (), lastinsertid is a method(), see updated answer

Comment: I use this: $waarde = $this->db->lastInsertId(); But for ID now I get 0. instead of 1059